# Allegro OrCAD Capture: Crashing after DRC check

Tags: pspice, orcad, cadence, allegro

**Issue:** The OrCAD Capture software by Cadence is continually crashing. The version I have is **SPB_16.5.**

**Problem:** I can run ONE DRC check fine, however; when I run another DRC on my schematic, the whole software crashes and I am no longer able to do any DRC checks on that project.

I even tested a completely working project from the past and ran a DRC check, it ran fine for FIRST DRC run but crashes on the second DRC run and never works again.

I have tried restarting the software, trying new projects, restarting the computer, and updating the cache on hierarchy.

It seems like there is an issue whenever I want to do more than one DRC check and something corrupts the project or something to do with the cache?

Any solutions to this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about proprietary soft running on a PC and not about EE but you have my sympathy.

Comment: You could try the Cadence forums or contact OrCAD support. I'd guess OrCAD would ask you to update your software.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but for some reason i'm getting "Access Denied" on their forums, even after a verified email and registration. So I came to these forums.

Comment: 16.5 is not the current release, maybe download the latest?

Comment: @Tyler I could try that but I am not sure if I have the access level to do that. Would have to fill a ticket for that.

Comment: https://support.cadence.com/

Comment: Be a man, don't do DRC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It was a problem with some internal library issue. The best way to fix this problem was just to delete this schematic and start a new project.